# Why does my PHP foreach loop only insert one value to SQL?

Tags: php, sql, xampp

I am trying to populate an SQL table with strings from an array called `$title`.

Here is my PHP code:

```
// To store the values to insert into the database tables.
$cid = 0; // Primary key.
$dates = array();
$number = array();
$title = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");
$description = array();

// For connecting to database.
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'contractsdb';

// Assign HTML file contents to $content.
$content = file_get_contents('C:\xampp\htdocs\HTMLParser/tester.html');

// Load HTML page into Document Object Model for parsing HTML.
$dom = new DOMDocument;    
$dom->loadHTML($content);

// Connect to DB and check connection.
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "$user", "$pass", "$db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Insert the values into the database contracts table.
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contracts (CID, TITLE)
                           VALUES ('$cid', '$title[$cid]')";
    echo "1 record added<BR>";
    $cid++; 
} 

// Error message if fail.
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

// Close connection to database.
mysqli_close($con);
```

When I run this code through XAMPP, and look at the table, I get this:
[image]
As you can see, **only one row is added**. What am I missing? 
Is there something wrong with the `foreach` syntax? 
The HTML page prints out 3 lots of "1 record added", **why doesn't the table contain 3 rows?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You overwrite `$sql` variable in each loop.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO contracts (CID, TITLE) VALUES ';

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
    $sql .= "($cid, '$title[$cid]'),"; // $cid is INT, so don't use quotes, in the second case you should you real_escape_string.
    $cid++; 
} 

if (!mysqli_query($con, rtrim($sql, ','))) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything is ok.

As u can see, You have echo in foreach loop but mysqli_query outside loop. So You execute only one statement:

```
INSERT INTO contracts (CID, TITLE) VALUES (2, 'ccc')
```